# Kali Linux 2021.2 (2009 Macbook Pro) can't access BIOS

Tags: kali-linux, macintosh, bios

I'm trying to boot from a flash drive on my macbook that I put kali on, but I can't get to the BIOS. I've tried the shortcuts that the machine is supposed to use, but nothing works. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your Mac book then press and hold the C key on your keyboard immediately upon hearing the startup chime.

I hope worked for you.

Comment: That opens up the GRUB BASH is there a way to boot from the flash drive through it?

Comment: Yes, Just step by step this commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html